# Using method inside a SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to use a method to construct a query in my model.

In my `User` model, there is a birthday attribute. And in `user.rb`, there is a method `age` that calculates user's age based on the value of the birthday attribute.

I am writing a scope inside `user.rb`, and I would like to select User objects where `age` is greater than the parameter passed in.

**Example**

```
scope :by_minimum_age, (min_age){
  where("age > min_age") if min_age.present?
}
```

This would not work because there is no such column as `age`. Any suggestions?

Comment: most databases have a method that can manipulate dates - you will need to look up what is available for yours and do something like this for age: "this year minus the year from the birthday"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like:

```
scope :by_minimum_age, ->(min_age) { where("birthday <= ?", Date.current - min_age.years) }
```